# Tempdata in ASP.Net MVC with JSON Request

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, json, jqgrid

I have an ActionResult that sets TempData to be an object.

The page that is rendered contains a button, that launches a JSON request to the same controller. (For jqGrid population).

The TempData on the JSON Request is null - why does this happen?

Even more bizarrely, if I had a button that posts to the same controller, and I click it instead of my JSON request button, TempData will be there, but if I click the JSON button, then the post button, TempData will be null.

Help appreciated.

Thanks,
Chris

Comment: Do you have any code samples you could show us?

Comment: I agree with James, we need to see code here.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Do not try to pass data from one action to another via TempData when not redirecting. [TempData is only for redirects](http://blogs.teamb.com/craigstuntz/2009/01/23/37947/). It is quite likely that some other element of your page is making a request before you press the button, causing the items you've squirreled away in TempData to vanish. That's why TempData is for redirects only; only when redirecting can you have *any confidence at all* of what the next request will be.

Instead, put the data in the rendered page. When you need to request an action that needs this data, pass it explicitly as a query string parameter.

HTTP is stateless. Learn to live with that. Don't try to introduce state to your server; you'll regret it if you do.